# Swift TCP connections on iOS

Tags: swift, tcp

For the past hour I have been trying to find any tutorial on how to make TCP connections on iOS. I found some code but nothing worked. I tried getting the code from different sources but as I said not a single thing worked. I just need a basic example, the rest will be done by me. For example lets say I need to send a string "Hello, World!" to address 192.168.0.1 port 1234. How would I go about it?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket.

Comment: Tried that but xcode says that swift version 3 is not compatible

Comment: Odd, I just downloaded the source and it builds fine, as does the example app. Where does your error occur?